# Enable Code Style in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, coding-style

I can see the Code Style scheme for Java under Settings - Editor - Code Style - Java.
[image: Settings - Editor - Code Style - Java]

The apply button is greyed out while the OK button is highlighted. I click on the OK button and get back to my project. But the Code Style doesn't have any effect when I write code. For instance, `for(int i=0;i<100;++1)` is not changed to `for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++1)` as per the scheme. Is there any other settings or configurations I need to do or is there any other way of keeping the code "neat"?

I'm using 
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1
Build #IC-145.258, built on March 17, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b18 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
on Gnome Ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA does not automatically reformat your code. Instead, you should press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to reformat your code on request.